# Lenovo G560 screen brightness control doesn't work

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, brightness

I recently installed Windows 8 Enterprise EVAL on my Lenovo G560 and the screen brightness control stopped working. I tried installing both the video driver from Lenovo's website and the one from NVIDIA. I also reinstalled Energy management but it didn't help. I also updated the BIOS version and reinstalled the monitor driver but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried compatibility with windows 7?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't help. The brightness slider's value changes but the screen stays the same.

Comment: Well, I haven't installed W8, but it could happen that the driver doesn't works with the SO, if lenovo doesn't support drivers for W8 and the compatibility doesn't work either, maybe it could be a good idea wait for the official release

Comment: Is the brightness adjusted using a special keyboard combination?  It may be a keyboard driver or software of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with windows 8. As soon as you update your video driver your brightness control is gone. I've got windows 7 and couldn't find a solution on the web. Don't bother writing the Lenovo-Service.

Never ever ever I will ever buy a Lenovo again. Never.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Lenovo forum](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G560-Screen-Brightness-Controll/td-p/391929) I was told to delete all occurrences of the key *EnableBrightnessControl*, using the Register Editor.  The keys can be found at;

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Class{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000]

This helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Lenovo IdeaPad U430 Touch with Windows 8.1 installed. After some automatic Windows updates the brightness function keys (F11 and F12) did not work anymore and the screen brightness was set to very dark.

To solve the problem I downloaded and installed the Lenovo recommended Intel Chipset driver (in my case this was Intel Chipset Device Software, Version 9.4.0.1026, dated on August 05 2013). After a reboot the function keys worked again and the brightness control too.

You can find the packages for your laptop on
http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products?type=Laptops-and-netbooks&c=1
Choose your laptop model and "Chipset" for the software package.